# Facebook API for Java application (for example, using the Swing library)

Tags: java, facebook, api

I have to write an application which will use some Facebook API to connect with a user account, check the user's message box, and maybe checks the user's wall.

Among others, I saw http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api, but getting the started guide shows how to do it only for [servlets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet).

Comment: Cool.  ..Did you have a question?

Comment: Because of authentication requirements, you may have to embed restful APIs in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be an official way to do this, most likely because of authentication requirements. You have to embed [restful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) APIs in your application. The REST API, that you can use to call Facebook from a Java application, is at http://restfb.com/.